# MySQL Query to display only latest records by latest date stamp (group)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to display only the latest records based on latest date.

Here is my table

```
client    dateadded   computername    title
 abc      2019-02-02    12345a         xyz
 abc      2019-02-02    12345b         xyz 
 abc      2019-02-02    12345c         xyz
 abc      2019-02-02    12345d         xyz
 abc      2019-02-09    12345e         xyz
 abc      2019-02-09    12345f         xyz
 abc      2019-02-09    12345g         xyz
 abc      2019-02-09    12345h         xyz
 abc      2019-02-09    12345j         xyz
 abc      2019-02-16    12345x         xyz
 abc      2019-02-16    12345s         xyz
 abc      2019-02-16    12345w         xyz
 abc      2019-02-16    12345bs        xyz
```

My desired output is

```
 abc      2019-02-16    12345x         xyz
 abc      2019-02-16    12345s         xyz
 abc      2019-02-16    12345w         xyz
 abc      2019-02-16    12345bs        xyz
```

In WordPress, I have that WHERE client = %CURRENT_USER_LOGIN%

This is my code

```
SELECT computername
     , title 
  FROM admin_mydb.s1 
 WHERE client = %CURRENT_USER_LOGIN%
 order 
    by datescanned
```

This of course will display all records for the currently logged in user. OK.

Now the code I've tried.

```
SELECT computername
     , title   
  FROM admin_mydb.s1 
 WHERE client = %CURRENT_USER_LOGIN% 
   and dateadded IN (SELECT max(dateadded) )
```

No luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT computername, title 
FROM admin_mydb.s1 
WHERE client = %CURRENT_USER_LOGIN% 
and 
dateadded IN (
SELECT max(dateadded) 
FROM admin_mydb.s1
)
```

You can also use self join inplace of sub query.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!